# preg match at index 0

Tags: php, regex

**Example:**

```
%body
The family is a central socialization context from early childhood 
behavior \cite{dishi-sto2007,hengg-etal1998,johns-etal2005}.

Family management becomes more challenging for parents during the 
transition from middle childhood to adolescence. Typically developing
```

**Explanation:** I need to  the extract the content from the string `"%body"` until **first paragraph**.

I'm using `preg_match( '/%body\\n(.*?)\\n/', $text, $matches );` to extract.

**output:**`The family is a central socialization context from early childhood`

As `\n` character is in all the lines, am getting a line in the string. So how to find the `\n` character at index 0 using regex, so that I can extract by paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable DOTALL modifier to make dots in your regex to match even line breaks also.

```
preg_match( '~(?s)%body\n(.*?)(?:\n\n|$)~', $text, $matches );
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/4)

Get the string you want from group index 1.

Comment: Thank you. how to get all the paragraphs  in the string? I need to add <p> tags in each of the paragraph. I tried `(?s)\n\n(.*?)(?:\n\n|$)`  with the string of 5 paragraphs but it matches only 1,3,5th paragraph. How to get all the paragraphs to be matched

Comment: try this `(?s)\n\n\K.*?(?=\n\n|$)`, or `(?s)%body\n\K.*?(?=\n\n|$)` then print the group index 0. and you need to use preg_match_all function to return more than one match.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked.  But regular expression seems lik very tedious to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
%body\n([\s\S]*?)\n(?=\n|$)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/16